# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save' using django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

```
opportunity = Opportunity.objects.filter(created_by__client=client, id=pk).exclude(is_deleted=True)

for opp in opportunity:
    id = opp.id
    name = opp.name
    contact = opp.contact.id

project = Project.objects.filter(client=client)    
project.opportunity = id
project.name = name
project.contact = contact

project.save()
```

Comment: Use **`Project.objects.get(client=client)`**

Comment: Are you trying to update a single Project obj? or a group of Projects?

Answer (score 0):

`Project.objects.filter(client=client)`
this returns a set of objects. If you want to retrieve only 1 object use  `Project.objects.filter(client=client).first()` or `Project.objects.get(client=client)`(recommended)

Then use `.save()` method it will work properly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update only one entity in django queryset. You need get it with `.first()`(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#first) or `.get()`(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#get) methods:

```py
id = opp.id
name = opp.name
contact = opp.contact.id
project = Project.objects.filter(client=client).first() # get first value from qs

project.opportunity = id
project.name = name
project.contact = contact

project.save()
```

Also you could update all queryset elements with `.update()`(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#update) method :

```py
id = opp.id
name = opp.name
contact = opp.contact.id
project = Project.objects.filter(client=client).update(
     opportunity=id,
     name=name,
     contact=contact,
)
```